# Multiple in select statements in single query

Tags: mysql, adodb

Currently, I am trying to select a list of posts from people who are friends and/or are being followed by the current user. However, I am running into an issue when I add in the second statement for the `following` table.

```
SELECT * FROM login, threads WHERE login.id=threads.poster_id AND deleted=0 AND login.id
   IN ((SELECT CASE WHEN second_id=? THEN first_id ELSE second_id END FROM friends WHERE first_id=? OR second_id=?)
   AND (SELECT CASE WHEN follower=? THEN following ELSE follower END FROM following WHERE follower=?))
ORDER BY threads.posted DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Is your “issue” a syntax, execution, results...?

Comment: There aren't any results as expected, however, it does work perfectly fine when one of the select statements is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two explicit `IN` conditions with the two subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM login
INNER JOIN threads
    ON login.id = threads.poster_id
WHERE
    deleted = 0 AND
    (login.id IN (SELECT CASE WHEN second_id=? THEN first_id ELSE second_id END
                  FROM friends WHERE first_id=? OR second_id=?) AND
     login_id IN (SELECT CASE WHEN follower=? THEN following ELSE follower END
                  FROM following WHERE follower=?))
ORDER BY
    threads.posted
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

This may fix the syntax errors and even give you the output you expect, but I also feel that we may be able to clean up the query a bit more.  Sample data would go a long way towards that end.

Comment: Yep, this did the trick - thanks for the help!

Also, in what ways would you recommend I clean up the query? I've changed it to order by the id instead of time which should have an impact performance wise.

Comment: @SecureServer I meant that maybe we could rewrite to avoid those subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'm gonna try to optimize the query more now that it's working.